# Position-independent code dectection

Tags: elf, pie

Is it possible to detect whether a given executable is a PIC by looking at the disassembler's output? If not, what are other valid ways to go about this?

Comment: What's the basis for the question? As is, it is a bit odd, so maybe if you explain your motivation it's possible to give a more helpful answer. If code is PIC, you usually see some typical patterns like `call $+, pop` to get the current address, or `call xxx, pop` to push some address on the stack.

Comment: @JohannAydinbas I don't really have a reason... I was just trying to understand the differences between ET_DYN and ET_EXEC(compiled with -fPIC) and that made me wonder whether I could detect this kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Detection by analysing assembly

It will highly depend on the compiler used, but here are some constructions that will differ between position independent and position dependent code:

- if you spot a `jmp` to an absolute address, that will mean that it is PDC (only jumps relative to `RIP` will be used in PIC)
- when some data is referenced by absolute address, it is PDC
- as @Johann Aydinbas noticed, when you see patterns like `cal $+, pop` or `call xxx, pop` to push some absolute address onto the stack, it will likely be PIC

## Detection by opening with debugger

You may also take advantage of the fact, that when you load position independent program and check address of some function, `main` for example, it will change each time you load it (because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)). The same won't be true for PDC - all addresses will remain the same.

## Detection by reading the ELF header

Why making your job hard analysing the executable, while it provides explicitly the information you need. As you noted in the comment, `ET_EXEC` value of `e_type` will be present in PDC, while `ET_DYN` will appear in PIC. And, according to the second answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/why-does-gcc-create-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary-according-to), this is the information used to determine whether `ASLR` may be used, in `Linux`.

## Other methods

You may of course use other tools for this purpose, like `file` or `readelf` for instance.